# Rest endpoints structure

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design, http-verbs

Supposing I have requirements:

- Register by email
- Register by social network
- Login by email
- Login by social network
- Logout
- Get my Profile
- Edit my Profile
- Get some user profile
- List my friends
- List some user friends
- Invite friends from social network
- Add product
- Edit product
- Search Product
- List my products
- List some user products

How should be endpoints REST API structure?

Answer (score 1):

Always ask yourself:

> What are my Resources?

- Register by email `POST /api/registration`
- Register by social network `POST /api/providerRegistration`
- Get some user profile `GET /api/user?userId={userId}`
- List my friends `GET /api/friends`
- List some user friends `GET /api/friends?userId={userId}`
- Add product `POST /api/product`
- Edit product `PUT/PATCH /api/product/{productId}`
- Search Products `GET /api/products?status={status}`
- List my products `GET /api/products?userId={userId}`

And so on - you get the gist of it. Note that the path (REST Resource) is a noun (`product`), not a verb (`search`).

Comment: `GET /api/user?userId={userId}` should be `GET /api/users/{userId}`,                  
`GET /api/friends?userId={userId}` should be `GET /api/users/{userId}/friends`   
`GET /api/products?userId={userId}`should be `GET /api/users/{userId]/products`